# Dynamic WPF Datagrid. Calculate function column logic

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcolumn

I am trying to make an invoice program, and i am trying to show the objects in a dynamic way inside a `DataGrid`. There would be only one column that the object has "Name", and extra columns like tax%, discount % and amount.(As an `IntegerUpDown` from xceed Toolkit).

Now what i need is another column that will show the total price by taking the price per product(part of the original object), multiplying it by the amount, adding tax and removing discount%.

I have seen many implementations, but i cant understand the logic behind it. I will create an object (Item) with the attributes that i need (name, price) and some functions like "total_Price" and event PropertyChangedEventHandler? But how i will be able to connect the "tax" , "discount" that are at the same row? If i add them into the object Item and hence to be able to refer to them, how i will be able to manipulate them through the `DataGrid`. If i change them there (at the `DataGrid` through the `IntegerUpDown` button), will they change in the actual object?

I am really new with wpf and especially with data-templates and stuff so i cant really get my head around the logic of it! A hint would be good at least on how i could start!

Comment: If your ViewModel is binded to the datagrid and correcty implemented, sure, its properties will change when you manipulate the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a read-only property to your data class that returns the calculated total price. Don't forget to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface raise the `PropertyChanged` event for this property whenever any of the other properties are changed:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private double _price;
    public double Price
    {
        get { return _price; }
        set { _price = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(TotalPrice)); }
    }

    private double _tax;
    public double Tax
    {
        get { return _tax; }
        set { _tax = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(TotalPrice)); }
    }

    private double _discount;
    public double Discount
    {
        get { return _discount; }
        set { _discount = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(TotalPrice)); }
    }

    private double _amount;
    public double Amount
    {
        get { return _amount; }
        set { _amount = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(TotalPrice)); }
    }

    public double TotalPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return (_price * _amount + _tax) * (1 - _discount);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats really good! Thank you!  So now i have to databind the List<Invoice> with my Datagrid. Till now i am only using lists and ItemsSource. I believe this might work. But just to be sure, is that the right way to bind a IEnumerable entity to a WPF Datagrid?

Comment: Yes, bind the `ItemsSource` property to your `List<Invoice>`.